React level select drop down menu with unknown key pair dynamic values
I want to make a select dropdown menu with every option being depedent from the previous one. The data I am retrieving from database have that kind of form
> {"category_1": 
{"sub_1":{"price":3},
"sub2":{"price":2}},
"category_2":{"sub_1":{"price":2}," sub2":{"price":2}}}

The problem is that the depth of the object is dynamic and I can't figure out how to make the select dropdown with useState values because I can't know from the beginning how many attributes the data will have. I use a recursive function to flatten the object but I am stuck how to use the data in a select menu after that. Here is my code with the form where I want to display my data. The data are the business props
import flattenObj from "../hooks/useRecursion";

const BusinessForm = ({business}) => {





const arr = flattenObj(business.options)

console.log(arr)
return ( 
    <div>
        <h5>
            this is a businessform for {business.business_name}
        </h5>
       
       
        {arr.map((o)=>(
            <p>{o[0]}</p>
        ))
        
        }
        
           
       
    </div>
 );
}



export default BusinessForm;

and here is my recursive function that returns an array
const flattenObj = (ob) => {
 
    // The object which contains the
    // final result
    let result = {};
    let arr = []                            
    
    
    for (const i in ob) {
    //    console.log(i)
       
      
        
        // We check the type of the i using
        // typeof() function and recursively
        // call the function again
        if ((typeof ob[i]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(ob[i])) {
            const temp = flattenObj(ob[i]);
            
            // for (const j in temp) {
 
                // Store temp in result
                // result[i + '.' + j] = temp[j];  
                
                
                //{category_1:{sub_1:{"price":3},sub_2:{"price":2}},category_2:{sub_1:{"price":2},sub_2:{"price":3}}}
                arr.push([i,temp])
                
                // loop through the object "ob"
               
                   
                
               // }
        }
 
        // Else store ob[i] in result directly
        else {
            // result[i]=ob[i]
            arr.push(ob[i])
            
        }
    }
    
    return arr;
    
};
export default flattenObj;

Any thougths on how can this be done?
